# How do I convert this java code to sort out integers in MIPS?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, assembly, mips

I just need help on sorting out what translates with what.

```
public static void insert(int val,int[] arr){
int i;

  for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
    if(arr[i]>val)
    break;
  }

  for(int k=arr.length-2; k>=i; k--){
    arr[k+1]=arr[k];
  }

  arr[i] = val;

}
```

EDIT: Here is the code before, it is asking for the number of integers to input and i save each input onto the array.

```
.data
array:          .space 20 #5 integers for example
size:           .asciiz "Enter the number of integers you want to enter: "
prompt:         .asciiz "Please enter an integer: "

.text
.globl main


main:   # program entry
la $t0, array
lw $t0, 0($t0) 

la $a0, size        #print out the prompt 
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5       #get the input
syscall


la $t0, array   #load array into t0; t0 is lowerbound of array = iterator
move $t1, $v0       #move n into t1
sll $t1, $t1, 2     #create offset
addu $t1, $t0, $t1  #st1 = upperbound of array
loop:
slt $t2, $t0, $t1   #if $t0 < $t1(size) then = 1, else = 0 ; 0 < size
beq $t2, $0, endloop    #if 0, end the loop

la $a0, prompt      #print out the prompt
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5       #get the input 
syscall

move $s0, $v0
sw $s0, 0($t0)

jal SORT        #call function sort
add $t0, $t0, 4     #increment by 1
j loop
```

This function is meant to order integers one by one each time input is recieved (not after all input is known). I have my own conversion to mips below. I tested it out and it's not working.

assume var is $s0

```
SORT:
loop1:
li $t2, 0       # t= 0
add $t3, $t1, $0    #send my upperbound array to t3

slt $t8, $t2, $t3,  # i < array.length(upperbound),
beq $t8, $0, loop2  #if fails, go to loop 2
add $t2, $t2, 1     #increment 
j loop1

loop2:
sub $t5, $t3, 4
sw $t4, 0($t5)      # k = array.length-1
sge $t7, $t4, $t2   # k <= i
beq $t7, $0, end    #if fails, exit loop
sw $t6, 0($t4)      #array[k+1] = array[k]
sub $t4, $t4, 4     #decrement
j loop2

end:
sw $s0, 0($t1)      #arr[i] = val
jr $ra          #return
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about HOW it is not working?

Comment: @ScottHunter program is supposed to receive how much integers is inputted. Program stops after the first integer is received. So im thinking there's something wrong on my sort function that's stopping it

Comment: In this situation, you have to find the bug first. Why not run the code with your IDE's debugger and find out what's not working?

Comment: What is the value of $t1 before the loop? And why is your `slt` comparison between $t2 (i) and $t1 (val?) instead of  `arr[i] and val` as in the original algorithm? Why do you replace your loop counter in `$t2` by the result of the `slt`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, i meant the code just keeps running. So it's prob waiting for something. Theres no error showing.

Comment: @AlainMerigot $t1 is the array, ive added the beginning of the code for some context, if it helps.

Comment: You should `lw` from `$t3`somewhere before the `slt` in the first loop. And use `$s0` for the comparison.  You also realize that `$t3` always has the same value, which is probably not intended. Add 4 to $t3 when you update loop counter. And do not use $t2 at the same time for the loop counter and the slt target.

Comment: the $t3 is my array upperbound, the i is my $t2 though. Shouldn't i be incrementing the i? Also do you mean i should do a lw $t3 0($t1) ?

Comment: [sorting array in mips (assembly)](//stackoverflow.com/q/19212544) has a working (but inefficient) MIPS Insertion Sort that uses integer indices instead of pointers, so it has to scale them all the time.  If you want help debugging this attempt, make it a [MCVE] by explaining (in the question, not comments) how it's not working, and use your debugger to find out where your code is getting stuck, and what values are in registers.